# Question about random variables convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Further going through old lecture notes I've stumbled upon this...

Let's say we are dealing with a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-1)\to N(0,2)$ in distribution. Our aim is to find limiting distribution of standarized sequence $\{\sqrt{X}_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

to be quite honest I have no idea how to approach this task. I tried to go through other notes I have, but other than **CLT** and Slutsky's Theorem not much comes to my mind. I've tried to work with that from the definition, to try to somehow transform a sequence of interest into a more appealing form but then I am mostly stuck. First o all I don't know a thing about its Variance or mean. It seems as though, it would be some transformation of limiting distribution parameters from the original series, but again I have no clue how to approach this.

I'd be most grateful if someone could lend me a hand in this task.

Comment: What is "CTG" ?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I've meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem , but switched to my native langue, where its abbreviation is CTG

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the delta method, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)

Comment: You can write $\sqrt{n}(X_n-1) = G_n$ where $G_n$ converges to a Gaussian $N(0,2)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  So then $X_n = 1 + \frac{G_n}{\sqrt{n}}$, which could potentially be negative so that $\sqrt{X_n}$ does not make sense.  But if we assume $X_n\geq 0$ always then 
 $\sqrt{X_n} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{G_n}{\sqrt{n}}}$ which simply converges to 1 in probability.

Comment: Okay If I got it right, from Delta method with functionm $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ sequence $\sqrt{n}(g(X_n-g(1))\to N(0,2\frac{1}{2^2})$, but as we are dealing with standarized sequence, $g(x)$ becomes $g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}-\mu_{\sqrt{X_n}}}{\sigma_{\sqrt{X_n}}}$ and given that function, sequence as mentioned above (with updated version of function $g$) converges to $N(0,\frac{2}{4\sigma^2_{\sqrt{X}_n}})$ and that is the most we can say about limiting dist. of the chain, as we don't know either the mean or the standard deviation of original series, and other than that we have to go by Michael's advice